# Match last values of different variables from a table

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a table storing values of A and B for different dates. It looks like this:

```
Date   Amount   Type
2015    15        A 
2014    -3        B 
2013     8        B 
2013    10        A 
2012     5        A
```

etc.

How to  **most effectively**  prepare a table that lists current A and current B value for each date? The idea is that for each date, one of the values is specified directly but the other one needs to be the last previous one.

```
Date   A   B
2015  15  -3
2014  10  -3
2013  10   8
```

etc.

The dataset will be a substantial one (millions of records), I'll appreciate your help. The solution will be implemented in SAS, so I'll use SAS procedures or the proc sql procedure (it has its limitations when it comes to self-joins).

Comment: I think a data step with `retain` is your best bet.  SAS proc sql is missing some key functionality, without which, the syntax really obscure.

Comment: How are you approaching it now? You say 'most effectively' - so what are we comparing this to?  And what's important - speed, simplicity, reusability?  At minimum, provide your code for how you're trying to do this now, please.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thank you, a data step with retain as proposed by DomPazz did just fine. Out of curiosity, what are the missing functionalities from the proc sql that would make it easier in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon says in the comments, I would use a Data Step and a `RETAIN` statement

First, create your data set.

Second, sort it in ascending order by DATE

Third, use the Data Step and `RETAIN` to create your values.  Use the BY statement and the subsetting `IF` to output all values for a given DATE.

Finally, sort in descending order by DATE to give you the order you want.

```
data have;
input Date   Amount   Type $;
datalines;
2015    15        A 
2014    -3        B 
2013     8        B 
2013    10        A 
2012     5        A 
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by date;
run;

data want(keep=date a b);
set have;
by date;
retain a b;

if Type = "A" then
    a = amount;
else if Type = "B" then
    b = amount;

if last.date;
run;

proc sort data=want;
by descending date;
run;
```

This produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to join back onto your table for each case.

I'm unclear what your logic for deciding whether to use the current or previous A amount or B amount is, but you should be able to fill it in for the statement below.

```
select distinct <br>
    dates.[date]<br>
    , CASE WHEN {condition for A} THEN currentA.amount ELSE prevA.amount END as A<br>
    , CASE WHEN {condition for B} THEN currentB.amount ELSE prevB.amount END as B<br>
from myTable dates<br>
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable currentA on dates.[date] = currentA.[date] and currentA.[type] = 'A'<br>
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable currentB on dates.[date] = currentB.[date] and currentB.[type] = 'B'<br>
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable prevA on dates.[date]-1 = prevA.[date] and prevA.[type] = 'A'<br>
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable prevB on dates.[date]-1 = prevB.[date] and prevB.[type] = 'B'<br>
order by dates.[date] desc<br>
```

For slightly better performance you can group the dates into a temp table and use that for the starting table rather than using the distinct keyword.  I haven't done that here to keep the query short.

Comment: You are assuming that there are no two year periods with gaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input Date   Amount   Type $;
cards;
2015    15        A 
2014    -3        B 
2013     8        B 
2013    10        A 
2012     5        A 
;
data want(keep=date A B);
   merge have have(firstobs=2 rename=(date=_date amount=_amount type=_type));
   retain flag;
   if date-_date=1 then do;
      if flag=1 then do;
           call missing(flag);
           return;
      end;
      if type='A' then do;
         A=amount;
         B=_amount;
      end;
      else if type='B' then do;
         B=amount;
         A=_amount;
      end;
      output;
   end;
   else if date=_date then do;
      flag=1;
      if type='A' then do;
         A=amount;
         B=_amount;
      end;
      else if type='B' then do;
         B=amount;
         A=_amount;
      end;
      output;
   end;
   else if missing(_date) then do;
      if flag=1 then return;
      if type='A' then A=amount;
      else B=amount;
      output;
   end;
run;
```